# Работа пк "во сне"

Tags: пк

Понадобилось сделать из домашнего пк что-то вроде мини-сервера под свои нужды. Однако, т.к. пк находится в спальне, не хотелось бы, чтобы он постоянно гудел.

Вспомнилось, что в режиме сна оперативная память питается. И при этом процессор может выполнять минимальный объём работы (?).

Все, что мне нужно - разбирать простецкие небольшие пакеты и отсылать ответы (или же будить пк, когда нужно выполнить что-то тяжёлое. Да, простой wake-on-lan не подходит по некоторым причинам).

Можно ли каким-то образом заставить пк выполнять код во сне? Или хотя бы просыпаться с какими-то интервалами, исполнять код и засыпать? (Делает же это как-то винда для своих обновлений).

Comment: Я бы посоветовал купить что то вроде малины(raspberry pi) И его уже заставлять делать все что захотите. 
А по вашей задаче наверное придется писать что то конкретное, на низкоуровневом скорее всего.

Comment: @АлександрСлепенков ну pi покупать не охота, есть только ардуино мега... А с её помощью не так просто будет запилить. Потому и вопрос чисто про пк, меня не особо пугает низкий уровень, для меня это больше как челлендж

Comment: Устройство с пассивным охлаждением — решение вашей проблемы. Не обязательно малинку, можно сервер даже на старом Android-телефоне поднять

Comment: Гудят вентиляторы и диски. Если кулер заменить [на большой радиатор без вентилятора](https://tiptopshoppingcart.com/images/Tiptop%20Shopping%20Cart_%20Zalman%20FX100%20Ultimate%20Fanless%20CPU%20Cooler_03.jpg) и поставить ссд, то ничего гудеть не будет. Можно и не очень большой, если тяжелых задач не планируется и вентиляция более-менее есть.

Comment: @Эникейщик дело в том, что сборка не плохая, на i5-6600k стоит вполне себе тихий кулер с огромным радиатором (который вообще не слышен). Ссд стоит, при этом m.2. pci-e. И даже небольшие кулерочки, что стоят в блоке, сами по себе не шумят. На видяхе при простое вентиляторы вообще не крутятся. А шумит это дело все вместе. Чутка гула дросселей блока, чутка шума вентиляторов, чутка пассивно-активно-агрессивного освещения - и все, из тихих компонентов собран гремучий монстр))0)

Comment: @andreymal да, с андроид-мобилкой хорошая идея, днем все думал об этом. Если его подключить к локальной wifi, то и wake-on-lan вполне можно будет рассылать при необходимости.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Можно ли каким-то образом заставить пк выполнять код во сне?

Нет, пока компьютерам не снятся электроовцы, а во всех S* [состояниях ACPI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACPI#%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) («S0» не считается) процессор не может производить ни какой работы, а в `S3`, в частности, питание процессора отключается. Обработка прерываний, по которым происходит выход из состояний производится независимо от ЦП.

> Или хотя бы просыпаться с какими-то интервалами, исполнять код и засыпать?

А вот это вполне возможно: идея в том, чтобы включить будильник в [RTC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8B_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8) BIOS'а по прерыванию от которого и будет происходить пробуждение.

Для x86 низкоуровневый интерфейс описан в документации от intel:

- [Accessing the Real Time Clock Registers and the NMI Enable Bit](https://www.intel.ru/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/real-time-clock-nmi-enable-paper.pdf) (PDF)

Пример реализации настройки регистров можно посмотреть в исходниках linux: [`cmos_set_alarm`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.1/ident/cmos_read_alarm)

Как можно заметить из документации, реализация intel'а позволяет установить  время пробуждение только в формате будильника (ЧЧ:ММ:CC), что не даёт отсрочить запуск более чем на 24 часа.

На linux'е, в первом приближении, довольно просто управлять всем этим прямо из пользовательского пространства, достаточно записать время пробуждение в unix-формате в [соответствующий файл](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/rtc.txt) и [уйти](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/states.txt) в спящий режим:

```
 # Установить будильник через две минуты
 echo $(date -d '+2min' '+%s') >/sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm
 # Войти в S3 (заснуть в память)
 echo mem >/sys/power/state
```

Дальше остаётся только завернуть это в цикл, придумать, что делать и условие выхода из цикла (например, если окажется, что пробуждение произошло раньше, чем ожидалось по таймеру) и костылик, считай, готов.

Какие интерфейсы для этого есть в win и других системах, я не знаю.

---

Использована информация из ответа: [How do wake timers work?](https://superuser.com/questions/949540/how-do-wake-timers-work#answer-949549)

Comment: Спасибо за конкретику. Получается, если пробуждение производится прерыванием и без участия (ну почти) софта, то невозможно отследить, был ли разбужен компьютер пользователем или таймером, и остается лишь сверять время при пробуждении с запланированным? И да, если придут какие-то пакетики по сети в то время, как пк спит, они буферизируются где-то на уровне железа, или же я их, по сути, упущу?

Comment: @selya, честно сказать не уверен, как узнать, что вызвало пробуждение. Инстинктивно кажется, что эта информация должна где-то сохраняться, а раз она сохраняется, то должен быть способ её получить, но на поверхности ничего найти не удаётся... по различным SE и прочим форумам разбросаны вопросы, но ничего полезного в них не видно... Сетевые пакеты, само собой, пропадут... хотя, возможно, несколько в буфере карты и останется... сетевая карта может не выключаться (на шпионских матерях intel даже в S5).

Comment: Ага, ну понятно. Тогда я уже сам порою конкретно то, что мне нужно, но скорее всего остановлюсь на варианте с андроид-мобилкой, как предложили в комментах выше. Спасибо, на мой вопрос вы вполне ответили, поставлю галку